# Windows 10 keeps changing default applications for opening video and music

Tags: windows, windows-10

Could you please tell if its possible to remove that odd behaviour.

I tried

1. Adding NoOpenWith keys to registry
2. Set applications via System
   settings.
3. Remove that MS crapware

But after a while this crap is associated again with MP3 and AVI files! Moreover, crap gets installed again!

I'm thinking about returning to Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: "I'm thinking about returning to Windows 7 Ultimate."  good plan Windows started "persistent" extension associations with GUID's in registry well before Win10 and made them even more persistent in Win10. Generally it is supposed to stick after two consecutive user choices. But not always the case with persistent repairs from applications changing associations.  I use Winpatrol to monitor changes but Win10 kept putting them back, so then I got into the root of the GUID associations for extensions and removed MS apps then got tired of doing that and dumped WinX

Comment: I just thought if its possible to make registry read-only for System user. Does it will break system or not

Comment: you can use procmon.exe to trace .avi then the find the GUID AVI and include a filter for this and then find all the entries.. but this has a steep learning curve for this tool.